# I can not call riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc in archlinux

Tags: zsh, archlinux, riscv, xv6

After installed the toolchain of xv6 needed on archlinux, following [Tools Used in 6.S081](https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.S081/2020/tools.html) , I run the `riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc --version`, but my command line shows `zsh: command not found: riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc`, how can I do next?

Comment: what is the result of `find / -name riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc` ?

Comment: @SteveWilson: _how can I do next?_  I would first invoke the command using an explicit path, to see that it is installed correctly. If this is the case, you would fix your `PATH variable (or `path` array, since you are on zsh), unless you always want to call it with an explicit path.

Answer (score 0):

In my archlinux, use the `riscv64-linux-gnu-gcc` command to compile, in macOS I use `riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc`, maybe try the first one, Or try typing risc and then pressing the tab key, maybe the shell will help you complete the rest of the command